# Passing a jquery method as a parameter into a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to pass a jQuery method as a parameter into a function , for example:

```
function set_action(a,b)
{
  $(a).b;
}

$(function(){
    $('#div_id1').click(function(){
        set_action('#div_id2','hide()');
    });
});
```

?

Comment: eval the code if you want to do it that way `eval("$('"+a+"')."+b);`

Comment: Don't use `eval()`!!! Stay away from `eval()`.  Its extremely inefficient!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access any property of an object with a string using bracket notation:

```
var foo = {
   bar: 5
};

console.log(foo['bar']);
```

So you could do:

```
function set_action(a,b) {
  $(a)[b]();
}

set_action('#div_id2','hide');
```

Note that this will throw an error if the object does not have a callable property with that name.

Comment: You can check to see if the object has a callable property using `$.fn.hasOwnProperty(b)` (when checking jQuery objects, use `$.fn`), or `typeof $(a)[b] === 'function'` or `b in $(a)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function set_action(a,b) {
   $(a)[b]();
}


$('#hello').click(function(){
  set_action('#bye','hide');
});
```

[See it working.](http://jsfiddle.net/CG4Uk/)